# Assign flag based on vector match in subsequent rows

Tags: r, matching

I have a dataframe that consists of a database of fishing permit holders that I merged with a database of registered boat owners such that fishing permit holders who have a registered boat have a "BoatOwner" flag = 1. The combined database has a "HouseholdID" whereby people living in the same house are assigned the same unique number. Within a household that has a registered boat, only the person to whom the boat is officially registered is flagged as a boat owner. How can I assign the subsequent people in the household as boat owners as well? I have sorted my database by "HouseholdID" and "BoatOwner" so that the boat owner in the household is listed first within each unique household. I don't know how to find a vector match in subsequent rows, and then if there is a match, assign a flag (0 or 1) to "BoatOwner".

Does anyone have any ideas to get me started?

Comment: if `dat` is your dataframe, try `dat$BoatOwnerInHousehold <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) any(dat$BoatOwner[dat$HouseholdID == x['HouseholdID']]))`

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example below, in future good idea to put a small sample of data using dput().

You can use dplyr's group_by to group the HouseholdID's and then find the max of BoatOwners and assign it to itself (or create an additional column) using mutate.

Note this approach doesn't require the data to be sorted in any particular order

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(HouseholdID = rep(1:5,each = 3), BoatOwner = c(rep(0,6),1,0,0,1,rep(0,5))) 
dat <- dat %>% group_by(HouseholdID) %>% mutate(BoatOwner = max(BoatOwner))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This code assigns BoatOwner=1 to every record in the dataframe (all  566,000 records). I need it to look within a household group and if at least one person is flagged as a boat owner, then all people within the household group should be flagged.

Comment: I tried this and think I arrived at my solution. Still checking the data. 

dat <- ddply(test, .(householdID), mutate,
                     BoatHH=max(Boat))

Comment: Hmm, it should not have assigned BoatOwner=1 to every record (it did not for me with the sample data I made) I think it does happen sometimes when there are conflicts between libraries, or possibly different versions (I'm using dplyr 0.7.2)